# Check if DOM element attribute is not empty

Tags: php, dom

I would like to check if an attribute exists and if it is not empty.
I use the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) to explore the DOM. I tried to look under the Attribute Filters tab.

As an example I got this:

```
if ( $html->find('meta[property=og:locale]') && IfNotEmptyCondition )
{
    foreach ($html->find('meta[property=og:locale]') as $element) {
       echo $element->content;
    }
} else {
    echo 'Votre site ne propose pas la balise <em>OG:locale</em>';
}
echo '<br>';
```

In the *if* I don't know how to look if the og:locale attribute is not empty.

Comment: I finally got this to work:

    if( $html->find('meta[property=og:locale]') ){
 foreach($html->find('meta[property=og:locale]') as $element){
  if (($element->content) !=='') {
         echo $element->content;
     }
  else{
   echo 'Votre site ne propose pas la balise og:locale';
  }
 }
    }
    else{}

Comment: It's also very okay you answer your own question. It's even better than forcing all that code into a little comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a little different angle: You do that by skipping the empty ones inside the `foreach` with the help of [`continue`](http://php.net/continue):

```
$elements = $html->find('meta[property=og:locale]');
foreach ($elements as $element) 
{
    if ($element->content === '') {
        continue;
    }
    echo $element->content;
}
```